# How do I set up the Workflow module?

Tags: 7, workflows

My site has an administrator role (editor), and I want to allow the anonymous users to submit articles in my site; the node they create must be approved by editor users, before to be published.
I have been told to use the Workflow module; I installed the module, and set it, but I didn't obtain what I wanted.

These are the steps I followed:

- I created a workflow which is named "teststory",  and added the "approve" state, which is applied only to the "story" content type.
- I edited the workflow, which is then shown as

```
   from/to     approve  
   (creation)  checked the author and authenticated user  
   approve     nothing
```

- Under the "access control" approve part, I allowed the authenticated user to view, edit, and delete the posts that are in this state.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you have only one state (*approve*). You really want to have at least two. Try adding *draft*. Configure the workflow so that on creation the node goes to the *draft* state. This should work:

```
From / To     draft      approved
(creation)    author         -
draft                    editor
approved        -
```

Comment: i have added a state draft, but i don't know which role i should check?

Comment: on the creation line there are two part(draft,approve). on the draft line, there is only approve with some roles. on the approve line,there is only draft with some roles, i don't know which role i should check? expect you can explain it to me. thank you

Comment: @enjoylife I've updated the answer

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are half way there, you should only need to either setup actions or use the Rules contrib Module...

Some tips for setting up Workflow:

1. If you encounter problems getting a module to work as expected, read the readme.txt file in the Module folder
2. For setting up Worflows, use 2 browsers (one logged into your site as the editor and the other as an anonymous user), this way you can quickly test to see if everything is working correctly and compare the editors displayed for each role.
3. You need to decide if you want to use the core actions or the contrib module Rules. Personally I prefer Rules. Once you have chosen you make it so that when a workflow state changes to "x" Drupal automatically publishes the content.